# Usando Select android studio

Tags: android, select, crud

Consegui salvar informações no meu banco do SQLite, só que não consigo chamar elas.

Estou tentando usando o seguinte método:

```
  private void verPessoas() {
   ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> pessoas = new Read().getLista();
   for (int i = 0; i < pessoas.size(); i++) {
    RespostasAguaCasa p = pessoas.get(i);
    int a = p.getValoragua();
    impri.setText("+"+ a);
}

if (pessoas.size() == 0) System.out.println("# Não existe valor .");
```

}

READ

```
  public class Read {
        public ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> getLista() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = 
      Maindb.getInstancia().getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Maindb.TABELA;
        ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            do {
                RespostasAguaCasa resp = new 
               RespostasAguaCasa(c.getString(0));
                resp.setId(c.getInt(1));
                resp.setValoragua(c.getInt(2));
                resp.setAcordarhora(c.getInt(3));
                resp.setAcordarminu(c.getInt(4));
                resp.setDormirhora(c.getInt(5));
                resp.setDormirminu(c.getInt(6));
                lista.add(resp);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
            {
            }


}
c.close();
return lista;
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dei uma olhada no seu código e percebi que na classe **Read()**, quando você faz o **return lista;**, você está retornando a lista vazia recém criada e não está atribuindo o resultado da **query** a ela.

```
 ArrayList<RespostasAguaCasa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
 return lista;
```

Recomendo também que dê uma olhada nas bibliotecas de persistência de dados [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) e [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest). São mais simples de implementar, mas com um poder maior ou igual ao método "cru" de persistência.
Segue outro sample que tenho utilizando o *Room*, aqui está o link: [Sample Room](https://github.com/luciano01/catalogo-livros).

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Comment: Dei uma olhada me ajudou muito mesmo obrigado